# Prove that $ab\leq\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}a^2+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}b^2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

let a,b be real  numbers and $\varepsilon>0$. prove the above inequality. I dont know how to even start. please, I need your help.

Comment: visit:**http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference** to improve formatting and to learn to write in LATEX.

Comment: @Shobhit : Thanks much!!!

Comment: There's no quantification on the variable $\varepsilon$.

Comment: This is a one-liner with AM-GM.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: okay so I can get to $ab\leq\frac{1}{2}a^2+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}b^2$ but thats as far i can show....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Convince yourself that $0\leq (a-\varepsilon b)^2$.
2. Prove that $0\leq (a-\varepsilon b)^2\implies ab\leq\dfrac{1}{2\varepsilon}a^2+\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}b^2$.

Comment: wow! i don't know what i was thinking... thanks much!!!

Comment: @Dome You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is just AM-GM:
$$
ab=\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2}{\varepsilon}\cdot\varepsilon b^2}\leq \dfrac{1}{2}( \dfrac{a^2}{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon b^2)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Given a,b be the real no and ε>0

Let (a-b)²>=0

Then (a-εb)²>=0

By formula (a-b)²=a²+b²-2ab_

a²+ε²b²-2aεb>=0

a²+ ε²b²>=2abε

1/2εa²+ ε/2 b²>=ab hence proved

Comment: its the same answer as given by @Gitgud.